# Create a dynamic View based on changable partitions table

Tags: oracle, query-performance, sql-view

I have an application that reads from a view in oracle, that view reads from a big table, and the view included functions and joins with other tables.

the view takes a while to run because the table becomes bigger for each month.

I try to partitions the table by year and become faster than before.

my problem is how to create a view based on the changeable partition (by year).

Comment: You can create the view like `CREATE VIEW ... AS SELECT ... FROM ... PARTITON (...)` but I don't think this will help you.

Comment: unfortunately, that's a solution will not help me, because my partition is changeable.

Comment: Can you simply include the partitioned column in the view, and then read from the view with a condition that filters by the date? The partition pruning should be pushed down into the view and only choose the relevant partitions.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that PARTITION_COL is a date column that is your partitioning key, you could do this:

```
create or replace
view THIS_CURRENT_YEAR as
select *
from  MY_PARTITIONED_TABLE
where PARTITION_COL >= trunc(sysdate,'YYYY')
and PARTITION_COL <  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),12)
```

in this way you'll get partition pruning where possible.

Comment: Thank you Connor, I'll try it and I think it's helpful to me